# Checking Jenkins build status from only one pipeline and avoid from other pipeline pointing to same gitlab repo in PR build

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, gitlab

Hi I am having two jenkins pipeline pointing to same git repo one pipeline  is named as **mainpipeline** and other is **sit** pipeline. Before **sit pipeline** our git **PR** build is checking the build status from mainpipeline. But after introducing **sit pipeline** which is pointing to same git repo as mainpipeline, our git build status is start checking from sit pipeline . How should i avoid checking the git build status from the sit pipeline and check only from mainpipeline.

I have suppress the build check status in sit pipeline but sometimes its working and sometimes not below is the screen shot of configuration
[image]

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell from reading [the source code](https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-branch-source-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/io/jenkins/plugins/gitlabbranchsource/helpers/GitLabPipelineStatusNotifier.java), the build status notifications are basically hard-coded into the GitLab Branch Source plugin and cannot be disabled.  Therefore, without writing your own plugin or something like that, the only way I can think of to disable the build status notifications would be to use a different method of checking out the repository that does not use the GitLab plugin, e.g. using the `checkout` step with a direct url.